# upgrade ‘Azure.Messaging.EventHubs’ to 5.6.2 return 'EventHubs' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure' error when build

Tags: c#, azure, azure-eventhub

upgrade

and then build

return

'The type or namespace name 'EventHubs' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [sss-af-filter]'

'The type or namespace name 'EventData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [sss-af-filter]'

```
using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;

public Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventData Event;
```

is the high version of 'Azure.Messaging.EventHubs' changed the namespace name or rule?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the namespace for Azure Event Hubs has changed from `Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs` to `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs` in the latest version of the SDK. You should update your code to use the new namespace.

To fix the error, replace `using Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs;` with `using Azure.Messaging.EventHubs;` and replace `public Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs.EventData Event;` with `public Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventData Event;`.

[image]

Refer this [NuGet Official Site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/5.6.2) for more information on this package that supports the .NET Frameworks.